# Using tortoisesvn to make a local version of online repository

Tags: tortoisesvn, repository

I have a svn-repository on google-code, but because i dont want it to be open source, i want to make the repository on my local drive. I'm using tortoisesvn, and have tried different things.

- I make a new folder, rightclick->create repository here, then ok.
- I rightclick the folder and select the repo-browser which is empty (as expected).
- I then select tortoisesvn->export and select the googlecode repository in the top and my newly created repo in the second one, then press ok
- the downloading starts, things are looking good
- then i use the repo-browser to see what is in the local repository
- but i only see the 3 directories (branches,tags and trunk), all of them empty(!), no sign of what i just saw downloaded (am thoroughly confused by this)
- I check the actual folder, and all is present there

So how do i make a local copy of what i have on google code (complete history) and point my local working copy to the new local repo?

Comment: Not ideal, but usable solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106990/making-commits-to-a-local-copy-of-an-svn-repository

Answer (score 1):

`TortoiseSVN - Export` exports *local working copy* **to unversioned tree**.

`Repo Broswer - Export` exports *selected remote tree*.

Import from GC to local repo isn't possible this way